# How to pass password to su on a BusyBox based system?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, busybox

I have a shell script that needs certain commands within it to run as root. On trying to find out a way to pass the password to `su`, I couldn't find any suitable way to do this. Most of the results used `sudo`, which is not there on my system. I tried doing:

```
echo <password> | su
```

But this returned:
`su: must be run from a terminal`

Is there any way to make this work without having to use `sudo` and only `su`?

Comment: If you have SSHed into the box use ssh -t <hostname>

Comment: No I'm not doing that. I'm entering using adb shell.

Comment: I would look at `expect`, i guess something like `expect -c 'spawn su; expect password:; send "hunter2"; interact'`

Comment: It doesn't  have expect as well.

Comment: What you are trying to do is generally bad practice, and `su` intentionally doesn't allow it. Can you explain more about what you are really trying to accomplish, since there is probably a must better solution that you have not thought of yet.

Comment: @Z4-tier I work with a device which requires constantly switching from superuser and normal. And the password is kinda long. I can't change it to something small since I'm not the one who decides that. I have written a script to accomplish most of my work easily but this is creating an issue.

Comment: Can you install `sudo`  or `expect` ? I am sorry to say that `su` just will not do what you want here. The only other option I can think of (which you should absolutely not do) is to write your own executable that performs the privileged tasks and then install it setuid root (but really, don't do this... If comments could be downvoted I would downvote myself for suggesting it). Without more info I don't think there's much chance for a good answer (but maybe someone will prove me wrong).